# Uninstall Qt 4.5.3 from Mac OS X 10.7.4

Tags: macos, qt, qt4

Executing `sudo python '/Developer/Tools/uninstall-qt.py'` gives this output:

```
removing package docs
docs is not installed, skipping.
removing package headers
headers is not installed, skipping.
removing package examples
examples is not installed, skipping.
removing package plugins
plugins is not installed, skipping.
removing package tools
tools is not installed, skipping.
removing package libraries
libraries is not installed, skipping.
removing package debuglibraries
debuglibraries is not installed, skipping.
removing package translations
translations is not installed, skipping.
```

Qt 4.5.3 binary package is not being removed by this script. The script itself is looking for `/Library/Receipts/Qt_` files which are not there. Is this a bug with Qt 4.5.3 binary package?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

#############################################################################
##
## Copyright (C) 2009 Nokia Corporation and/or its subsidiary(-ies).
## Contact: Nokia Corporation (qt-info@nokia.com)
##
## This file is part of the Qt Toolkit.
##
## $QT_BEGIN_LICENSE:LGPL$
## No Commercial Usage
## This file contains pre-release code and may not be distributed.
## You may use this file in accordance with the terms and conditions
## contained in the either Technology Preview License Agreement or the
## Beta Release License Agreement.
##
## GNU Lesser General Public License Usage
## Alternatively, this file may be used under the terms of the GNU Lesser
## General Public License version 2.1 as published by the Free Software
## Foundation and appearing in the file LICENSE.LGPL included in the
## packaging of this file.  Please review the following information to
## ensure the GNU Lesser General Public License version 2.1 requirements
## will be met: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/lgpl-2.1.html.
##
## In addition, as a special exception, Nokia gives you certain
## additional rights. These rights are described in the Nokia Qt LGPL
## Exception version 1.0, included in the file LGPL_EXCEPTION.txt in this
## package.
##
## GNU General Public License Usage
## Alternatively, this file may be used under the terms of the GNU
## General Public License version 3.0 as published by the Free Software
## Foundation and appearing in the file LICENSE.GPL included in the
## packaging of this file.  Please review the following information to
## ensure the GNU General Public License version 3.0 requirements will be
## met: http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html.
##
## If you are unsure which license is appropriate for your use, please
## contact the sales department at http://qt.nokia.com/contact.
## $QT_END_LICENSE$
##
#############################################################################

import commands, sys, os, shutil, glob

trace = False
justTest = False
# Globals
AllPackages = ['docs', 'headers', 'examples', 'plugins', 'tools', 'libraries', 'debuglibraries', 'translations' ]

packagesToRemove = AllPackages

# Travese the list and remove values that won't work.
def realPackagesToRemove(packageList):
    for package in packageList:
        if package not in AllPackages:
            print "%s is NOT a valid package, removing it from the list" % (package)
            packageList.remove(package)
    return packageList

#Remove the files in the list
def removeFiles(fileList, helperFunc=0):
    directories = []
    for file in fileList:
        file = file[1:]
        if not os.path.islink(file) and os.path.isdir(file):
            directories.append(file)
        elif len(file) > 0:
            if os.path.exists(file) or os.path.islink(file):
                if trace:
                    print "remove file: " + file
                if not justTest:
                    os.remove(file) 
            elif not 'uninstall-qt.py' in file:
                print "file: %s does not exist, skipping" % file


    # Now remove any empty directories
    directories.reverse()
    for dir in directories:
        if helperFunc:
            helperFunc(dir)
        if (os.path.exists(dir)) and len(os.listdir(dir)) == 0:
            if trace:
                print "remove dir: " + dir
            if not justTest:
                os.rmdir(dir)
        elif trace and os.path.exists(dir):
            print "NOT removing " + dir

def removeExampleGeneratedFiles(dir):
    extraList = []
    extraList.append(os.path.join(dir, "Info.plist"))
    extraList.append(os.path.join(dir, ".DS_Store"))
    extraList.append(os.path.join(dir, ".qmake.cache"))
    extraList.append(os.path.join(dir, "Makefile"))
    extraList.append(os.path.join(dir, ".obj"))
    extraList.append(os.path.join(dir, ".moc"))

    xcodeprojects = glob.glob(dir + "/*" + os.path.basename(dir) + "*.xcode*")
    xcodeprojects += glob.glob(dir + "/.xcode*")  # Grab the items from qmake mess-up in 4.0.1

    for file in xcodeprojects:
        if trace:
            print "  removing the tree in " + file
        shutil.rmtree(file)

    for file in extraList:
        if os.path.exists(file):
            if trace:
                print "  removing the file in " + file
            if os.path.isdir(file):
                shutil.rmtree(file)
            else:
                os.remove(file)


# Remove the package
def removePackage(package):
    print "removing package " + package
    realPackageName = "/Library/Receipts/Qt_" + package + ".pkg"
    bomLocation = os.path.join(realPackageName, "Contents/Archive.bom")
    if os.path.exists(realPackageName) and os.path.isdir(realPackageName):
        fileList = commands.getoutput("/usr/bin/lsbom -f -p f -d -l " + bomLocation).split()
        if len(fileList) > 0:
            if (package == "examples"):
                removeFiles(fileList, removeExampleGeneratedFiles)
            else:
                removeFiles(fileList)
            shutil.rmtree(realPackageName)
    else:
        print "%s is not installed, skipping." % package


################# Here's where the actual script starts ########################################
if os.getuid() != 0:
    print sys.argv[0] + ": This script must be run as root or with sudo, exiting now."
    sys.exit(-1)

# Take the names of packages on the command-line
if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    packagesToRemove = sys.argv[1:]

packagesToRemove = realPackagesToRemove(packagesToRemove)

if len(packagesToRemove) < 1:
    print "\nNo valid packages to uninstall.\nusage: %s [package ...]" % (sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(1)

for package in packagesToRemove:
    removePackage(package)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use the `uninstall-qt.py` from Qt 4.6.3. It searches for receipts in `/var/db/receipts/.` in addition to `/Library/Receipts`

```
sudo python /Developer/Tools/uninstall-qt.py
```

Here's the contents of the 4.6.3 script

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

#############################################################################
##
## Copyright (C) 2009 Nokia Corporation and/or its subsidiary(-ies).
## Contact: Nokia Corporation (qt-info@nokia.com)
##
## This file is part of the Qt Toolkit.
##
## $QT_BEGIN_LICENSE:LGPL$
## No Commercial Usage
## This file contains pre-release code and may not be distributed.
## You may use this file in accordance with the terms and conditions
## contained in the either Technology Preview License Agreement or the
## Beta Release License Agreement.
##
## GNU Lesser General Public License Usage
## Alternatively, this file may be used under the terms of the GNU Lesser
## General Public License version 2.1 as published by the Free Software
## Foundation and appearing in the file LICENSE.LGPL included in the
## packaging of this file.  Please review the following information to
## ensure the GNU Lesser General Public License version 2.1 requirements
## will be met: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/lgpl-2.1.html.
##
## In addition, as a special exception, Nokia gives you certain
## additional rights. These rights are described in the Nokia Qt LGPL
## Exception version 1.0, included in the file LGPL_EXCEPTION.txt in this
## package.
##
## GNU General Public License Usage
## Alternatively, this file may be used under the terms of the GNU
## General Public License version 3.0 as published by the Free Software
## Foundation and appearing in the file LICENSE.GPL included in the
## packaging of this file.  Please review the following information to
## ensure the GNU General Public License version 3.0 requirements will be
## met: http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html.
##
## If you are unsure which license is appropriate for your use, please
## contact the sales department at http://qt.nokia.com/contact.
## $QT_END_LICENSE$
##
#############################################################################

import commands, sys, os, shutil, glob

trace = False
justTest = False
# Globals
AllPackages = ['docs', 'headers', 'examples', 'plugins', 'tools', 'libraries', 'debuglibraries', 'translations' ]

packagesToRemove = AllPackages

# Travese the list and remove values that won't work.
def realPackagesToRemove(packageList):
    for package in packageList:
        if package not in AllPackages:
            print "%s is NOT a valid package, removing it from the list" % (package)
            packageList.remove(package)
    return packageList

#Remove the files in the list
def removeFiles(fileList, helperFunc=0):
    directories = []
    for file in fileList:
        file = file[1:]
        if not os.path.islink(file) and os.path.isdir(file):
            directories.append(file)
        elif len(file) > 0:
            if os.path.exists(file) or os.path.islink(file):
                if trace:
                    print "remove file: " + file
                if not justTest:
                    os.remove(file) 
            elif not 'uninstall-qt.py' in file:
                print "file: %s does not exist, skipping" % file


    # Now remove any empty directories
    directories.reverse()
    for dir in directories:
        if helperFunc:
            helperFunc(dir)
        if (os.path.exists(dir)) and len(os.listdir(dir)) == 0:
            if trace:
                print "remove dir: " + dir
            if not justTest:
                os.rmdir(dir)
        elif trace and os.path.exists(dir):
            print "NOT removing " + dir

def removeExampleGeneratedFiles(dir):
    extraList = []
    extraList.append(os.path.join(dir, "Info.plist"))
    extraList.append(os.path.join(dir, ".DS_Store"))
    extraList.append(os.path.join(dir, ".qmake.cache"))
    extraList.append(os.path.join(dir, "Makefile"))
    extraList.append(os.path.join(dir, ".obj"))
    extraList.append(os.path.join(dir, ".moc"))

    xcodeprojects = glob.glob(dir + "/*" + os.path.basename(dir) + "*.xcode*")
    xcodeprojects += glob.glob(dir + "/.xcode*")  # Grab the items from qmake mess-up in 4.0.1

    for file in xcodeprojects:
        if trace:
            print "  removing the tree in " + file
        shutil.rmtree(file)

    for file in extraList:
        if os.path.exists(file):
            if trace:
                print "  removing the file in " + file
            if os.path.isdir(file):
                shutil.rmtree(file)
            else:
                os.remove(file)


# Look for the receipts in two locations: /Library/Receipts/ and
# /var/db/receipts/. (The receipts are not copied into
# /Library/Receipts when installing on Snow Leopard.)
def findReceipt(package):
    realPackageName = "/Library/Receipts/Qt_" + package + ".pkg"
    slashLibraryLocation = os.path.join(realPackageName, "Contents/Archive.bom")
    if os.path.exists(realPackageName) and os.path.exists(slashLibraryLocation):
        return slashLibraryLocation, realPackageName;

    slashPrivateLocation = "/var/db/receipts/com.trolltech.qt4." + package + ".bom"
    if os.path.exists(slashPrivateLocation):
        return slashPrivateLocation, slashPrivateLocation;

    if (package == "libraries"):
        package = "libs"
    if (package == "debuglibraries"):
        package = "debuglibs";

    slashPrivateLocation = "/var/db/receipts/com.trolltech.qt4." + package + ".bom"
    if os.path.exists(slashPrivateLocation):
        return slashPrivateLocation, slashPrivateLocation;

    return "", ""

# Remove the package
def removePackage(package):
    print "removing package " + package
    bomLocation, realPackageName = findReceipt(package)
#    print "package receipt at " + bomLocation + " " + realPackageName
    if os.path.exists(realPackageName):
        fileList = commands.getoutput("/usr/bin/lsbom -f -p f -d -l " + bomLocation).split('\n')
        if len(fileList) > 0:
            if (package == "examples"):
                removeFiles(fileList, removeExampleGeneratedFiles)
            else:
                removeFiles(fileList)

            if (os.path.isfile(realPackageName)):
                os.remove(realPackageName)
            else:
                shutil.rmtree(realPackageName)
 #   else:
 #       print "%s is not installed, skipping." % package

################# Here's where the actual script starts ########################################
if os.getuid() != 0:
    print sys.argv[0] + ": This script must be run as root or with sudo, exiting now."
    sys.exit(-1)

# Take the names of packages on the command-line
if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    packagesToRemove = sys.argv[1:]

packagesToRemove = realPackagesToRemove(packagesToRemove)

if len(packagesToRemove) < 1:
    print "\nNo valid packages to uninstall.\nusage: %s [package ...]" % (sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(1)

for package in packagesToRemove:
    removePackage(package)
```